# Uint8_to Char array Arduino sketch

Tags: arduino, arrays

I am using this sh1 function. Instead of printing the hash value I want to store it in a char array or string for further processing.

```
#include "sha1.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {



  uint8_t *hash;

  Sha1.init();
  Sha1.print("This is a message to hash");
  hash = Sha1.result();

   for (int j=0;j<20;j++)

   Serial.print("0123456789abcdef"[hash>>4]);
   Serial.print("0123456789abcdef"[hash&0xf]);

  }

  Serial.println();


 delay(1000);

}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Instead of printing the value I want to store uint8_t * hash (value) to char array or string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char digitArray[]= {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f'};

char buffer[40];


for (int i = 0; i<40; i+=2){

  buffer[i] = digitArray[(hash[i/2] & 0xF0) >> 4];
  buffer[i+1] = digitArray[(hash[i/2] & 0x0F)];
}
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: This is the answer. I am looking for this and it works.